# Use Async function to print value in ejs view Express js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I passed the model from controller to use it in view, but it seems like printing values using Async functions is not possible in a view. what could be the suitable way to use a model to print inside an async function in a view?

I need to get the userImage from user table.
(ps: use of console.log(userImage) in the same place is working, it's driving me crazy. please help me)

```
        <img src="<% userModel.findById(postData.uid,function(err,user) {%>   <%=user.userImage%>  <% }) %>" class="mx-2"><a href="#" class="mx-2">Anmol D. Pradhan</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, that's absolutely not the best practice.

You should do something like that:

```js
    // ...
    const userModel = require('/your-path-to/userModel');
    app.get('/your/url', async (req, res) => {
        const user = await userModel.findById(uid);
        res.render('/youpage.html', {
            user: user
        });
    });
```

```html
<!-- Here's your EJS template -->

<img src="<%= user.userImage %>" class="mx-2"><a href="#" class="mx-2">Anmol D. Pradhan</a>
```

That's just an example. I don't know how actually your routes structured, but I hope that will help.